Email with multipart information appears in textual format by receiving end
When sending an email with following PHP code, the email is received but shown in textual format. This appears to be the case on PHP 8+, on older versions 5.6 - 7.4 the script was working just fine. What would be the correct way of implementing on PHP 8+ ? I was not able to find any documentation / information on this issue.
$to = "Test Mail <test@test.gmail>";
$from = "Test Mail <test@test.gmail>";
$cc = "Test Mail <test@test.gmail>";

$subject = "TEST email";
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . "Cc: $cc";

$htmlContent = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fi-FI">
    <body>
        <h1>HEADER OF THE EMAIL</h1>
    </body>
</html>
';

// Boundary  
$semi_rand = md5(time());  
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    
// Headers for attachment  
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"\n";

// Multipart boundary  
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";


// Send email
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


I'd strongly recommend using a library such as PHPMailer to build your emails, then you don't have to worry so much about the finicky formatting of the different parts of the mail body, or the headers, and other things. Takes all the manual work out of it, instead you just call ready-made functions which take care of the irritating and hard-to-debug bits for you.

But equally, if you just want to send HTML content in your email then you don't need a complicatd multi-part message to begin with - you could just set the overall content-type as HTML and be done with it. There are plenty of examples of that online already.

AFAIK though upgrading to PHP8 should have no particular influence on any of this - are you sure that's all that changed? Because utltimately it's the mailserver which builds and sends the email based on what PHP provides to it. I can't see how anything you've written here would result in any different strings being provided to the mail function, just because of a version upgrade. Output in PHP 8.3.6: https://3v4l.org/hgaHu#v8.3.6 . Output in https://3v4l.org/hgaHu#v7.4.33 . They look identical to me.

FYI: That fake From: address you are setting, is a pretty good way to land in the spam folder (or worse, get the email rejected completely, silently, without any notice.) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux From: sender"

If you can downgrade to PHP 7 and the code produces a mail that is working: compare it to the mail from a later version of PHP and check it for differences. If you see any, please add them to your question
